# ActiveX component can't create object error. WebsiteError:8004e025

Tags: asp.net, vb6, activex, com+

When I am trying to hit my application url, I am getting ***"ActiveX component can't create object error. WebsiteError:8004e025***" error in the browser. This application is hosted in IIS and operating system is Windows Server 2003 32-bit. 
When I checked event viewer logs, I got following error:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source: COM+
Event Category: (98)
Event ID: 4840
Date: 06/06/2016
Time: 13:24:45
User: N/A
Computer: APW02508WCAPP02
Description:
The IObjectControl::Activate() method failed.  The CLSID of the object is:
{CAFBD1A2-73BD-438B-841C-A9C88BD4C248}

Server Application ID: {74CF179D-508C-43FE-AE29-B3480386BDE3}
Server Application Instance ID:{E7855B79-7A03-4E7A-8BA4-37666501917F}

**Error Code** = **0x800a01ad**  
COM+ Services Internals Information:
File: d:\nt\com\complus\src\comsvcs\jit\jit.cpp, Line: 475
Comsvcs.dll file version: ENU 2001.12.4720.3959 shp
```

I tried registering Comsvcs.dll and it got registered, but still I am getting same error. I know that this is not a code issue as this application works on other windows server 2003 machine. Only on this particular machine, I am getting this error. Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you enabled 32 bit applications in the app pool?

Comment: The application is hosted on Windows Server 2003 32-bit operating system. Still I have enabled 32 bit applications in the app pool. But still I am facing same issue.

Comment: You need to identify the ActiveX component that is failing.  The issue isn't `comsvs.dll`.  I'd start by using `comexp.msc`,

Comment: I have identified the ActiveX component that is failing. It is failing for Server.CreateObject("WebSite.GenericFunctionality"). This is for WebSite.dll. I tried registering this dll and it got registered properly. Also I tried to find if there is any dependent dll that is missing using dependencyWalker software. It did not showed any missing dlls. Still I am getting same error.

Comment: In Component Service MMC, on the Component Properties windows, open Advanced tab and check "Allow IIS intrinsic properties".

Comment: I am not able to see the option "Allow IIS intrinsic property" in Component Service MNC on the Component Properties window in advanced tab. I think for Windows Server 2003 32-bit operating, by default Allow IIS intrinsic property is true and for later versions of the operating system , it is by default set to false and so in later versions, there is option for this.